# Key listener java - number limitation

Tags: java, swing

I've got an app in JFrame. Here is part of the code:

```
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
  {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
                 String input = text.getText();
                 int number = Integer.parseInt(text.getText());
                 if(number>0)
                 {
                     for(int i=0; i<liczba; i++)
                     {
                         new NewWindow();
                     }
                 }
          }
  });
```

This action creates new windows in app where number of windows depend on number we've inputted. I need to make sure it IS a number (not a letter or something). I also know the key listener must be used and the symbol inputted has to be between some values of ASCII which represent numbers. But I don't know how to do this exackly. Any solutions?

Comment: Surround `int number = Integer.parseInt(input);` with a `try{...}catch(Exception e){}` If it gets to the `catch` portion that means its not a number

Answer (score 3):

> I also know the key listener must be used

No a KeyListener does not need to be used. That is probably the oldest solution and was used in AWT. Swing has newer and better API's which you should be using.

You could use a `JSpinner`, `JFormattedTextField` or a `DocumentFilter`.

Read the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). You should check out sections on:

1. `How to Use a Spinner`
2. `How to use Formatted Text Fields`
3. `How to Write a DocumentFilter`

Any one of the above is a better solution than using a KeyListener.